# Show that $(X,d)$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, product-space

Let $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. For $x=x_1x_2x_3\cdots$ and $y=y_1y_2y_3\cdots$ in $X$, define
\begin{align*}
d(x,y)=2^{-\min\{n\in\mathbb{N}:x_n\neq y_n\}}
\end{align*}

Firstly, I showed $(X,d)$ is a metric space. Next, I knew that the topology generated by the metric d is same with the product topology of discrete space $\{0,1\}$.

Thus, I get the $(X,d)$ is compact by using Tychonoff's theorem.

But, I want to know how to prove this fact without using Tychonoff's theorem...

Any help is appreciated!!

Thank you!!

Comment: Then prove that every sequence contains a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Hmm... I cannot think how to get convergent subsequence... Could you give some hints?...

Comment: Define $f\colon X\to [0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$ by $x=x_1x_2x_3\dotsc\mapsto\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_n}{2^n}$ and show that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @ChoF You then have $f(1,0,0,\dots)=1/2=f(0,1,1,\dots)$.

Comment: @RJM You are right. $f$ is not 1-1.

Comment: @w.sdka: This is Cantor's diagonal argument (see Kavi's answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is just Cantor's diagonal procedure. Start with a sequence in X and look at the first coordinates. You get a sequence of 0's and 1's. Obviously this has a convergent subsequence. Now look at the second coordinates along this subsequence and extract a convergent subsequence, etc. The 'diagonal' subsequence  has the property that each coordinate converges along this subsequence. Convergence of each coordinate is equivalent to convergence in the given metric.